# jQuery Autocomplete Plugin that triggers after token

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm building an application, and would like to do an autocomplete within a textarea, much like how Twitter/Facebook does theirs with the @[name].  However, I would like to it trigger when I enter [TID:x], where x is an integer of any length.

It appears that Twitter/Facebook start their autocomplete after you hit the @ sign, and then sends the text data after it for the autocomplete.  Does anyone have any idea if the jQuery UI plugin (or any other plugin) can do something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed possible.  You can tap into the autocomplete widget's events ([`search`](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-search) and [`select`](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select)) to accomplish this:

```
var triggered = false;
var trigger = "TDI:";

$("input").autocomplete({
    source: [...],
    search: function() {
        if (!triggered) {
            return false;
        }
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var text = this.value;
        var pos = text.lastIndexOf(trigger);

        this.value = text.substring(0, pos + trigger.length) +
            ui.item.value;

        triggered = false;

        return false;
    },
    focus: function() { return false; },
    minLength: 0
}).bind("keyup", function() {
    var text = this.value;
    var len = text.length;
    var last;
    var query;
    var index;

    if (triggered) {
        index = text.lastIndexOf(trigger);
        query = text.substring(index + trigger.length);
        $(this).autocomplete("search", query);
    }
    else if (len >= trigger.length) {
        last = text.substring(len - trigger.length);
        triggered = (last === trigger);
    }
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/kCkga/

**Notes:**

- This is a *very limited* demo.  It will not work if you try to make it autocomplete in the middle of the string.
- To complete this example, you'd need to do some work with figuring out the position of the cursor in the input field and inserting the text there instead
- Probably other bugs, but I definitely think it's doable.  Hope this gets you started.

Comment: Great!  This looks like it'll do the trick.  I'm going to mess with it over the next few days, and will respond if there's any other questions.  I'll mark it as an answer if it ends up working out!  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I have created a plugin for that, which uses jQuery-UI Autocomplete and Andrew's example (thanks for that).

Url: https://github.com/experteer/autocompleteTrigger

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dmattes/2YRgW/1/

```
$('input,textarea').autocompleteTrigger({
  triggerStart : '@',
  triggerEnd: '',
  source: [
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ]
});
```

Best,
Daniel

Comment: This is my favorite solution thus far.  Now if you could support contenteditable divs that would be perfect.