# jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to implement 'jquery ui autocomplete' in my website.

What happens is:

A user can mention other users like in Twitter using '@'.

Everything works well. But after the user has mentioned another user. So the message looks like e.g. 
"mentioning @user1"

Autocomplete still goes on even though the next word is not a user mention. If I disable the autocomplete after a succesful user mention, then doing the following is not possible.

"mentioning @user1 @user2" because for "@user2", the autocomplete is disabled.

any suggestions?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564378/jquery-autocomplete-plugin-that-triggers-after-token

there are two good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to take a look at the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple) for the multiple value implementation ? Although, it does have commas in between each value. Might be relevant.